# CoreML in Cocoapod (pod spec lint won't work)

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am attempting to update my cocoapod. Since the last update, I have added a `.coreml` file and not when I try `pod spec lint`, I am getting some errors. Things I've done:

1. Added `s.resources = "JacquardToolkit/**/*.mlmodel"` to my `.podspec` file

There was also a few name changes with my `.coreml` file. Ultimately I want to include only `ForceTouch.coreml`, so I also need help to get rid of the references to `Forcetouch.coreml` and `ForceTouch2.coreml`.

Here is the error message I get in terminal...[image]

Comment: Does your project even compile? Those are clearly Swift compiler errors, they don't have anything to do with `.coreml` files.

Comment: It does compile. The two issues of concern have to do with ForceTouch and ForceTouch input. They compile but since they come from an auto generated coreml file, they seem to be blocking my cocoapods update

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add the MLModel to your spec.source_files in your podspec:

```
spec.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.{swift,mlmodel,mlmodelc}'
```

You may also need this if it fails to compile because codegen language is not set:

```
spec.xcconfig = {'COREML_CODEGEN_LANGUAGE' => 'Swift', 'COREML_CODEGEN_SWIFT_GLOBAL_MODULE' => 'NO'}
```